# How to add lazy loading/infinite scroll on OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I have this code where whenever the button is click I will call a new page and I wanted it to append on certain div. However I get no value when I do a `console.log()` so I am having trouble getting the data in order to append it but I am able to successfully post and get `Status Code: 200`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.request('onLazyLoad', {
            success: function(data) {
                //Run lazy loading if enabled
                if(data.result == 'true') {
                    $('#btnLoadMore').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        $.request('onFilterItems', {
                            data: {
                                _session_key: $('input[name="_session_key"]').val(),
                                _token: $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                                Filter: {
                                    page: 4,
                                    sort: '',
                                    product_view: 'grid',
                                    search: '',
                                    priceFrom: '',
                                    priceTo: ''
                                }
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                        })
                    });
                } 
            }
        });
    });
```

The query actually works on the backend and I can use `dd()` however there are no data received on js.

This is the part where form_ajax is being used. The default implementation with pagination

```
{{ form_ajax('onFilterItems', { update: { 'products/products': '#partialListing', 'products/productsView' : '#product_listing_view' } }) }}
<div id="filterProperties" class="filter-wrap">
     <input type="hidden" name="Filter[page]" class="form-control" id="currentPage" value="1">
     <input type="hidden" id="searchFilterSort" name="Filter[sort]">
     <input type="hidden" id="product_view" name="Filter[product_view]" 
....

<!-- this is where I wanted to append the result  -->
<!-- rather than changing it to another page  -->
<div class="row" id="partialListing">
   {% partial 'products/products' %}
</div>
```

Comment: can you pelase share your network request log from the dev tools. ref" https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/

Comment: Yes the network request log and the PHP code. Maybe you are returning any data in the response.

Comment: @PettisBrandon and Hardik Satasiya the value the on the '$this->products' is a model which is the result from the pagination but what I get on the console log is like this "[]"

Comment: @OliverMaglana Edit your question and add the php code.